# Как исключить вывод записей по тегу в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

У записей есть теги либо `['a', 'b', 'c']`, либо `['a', 'b']`. Как можно сделать вывод записей в WP только записи, которых в тегах отсутствует тег 'c'? Такой синтаксис не работает `'tag' => !'c',`

Comment: tag__not_in. Читайте документацию: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#taxonomies

Comment: не работает, все равно выводит все посты. и те у которых ['a', 'b', 'c'], и у кого просто ['a', 'b'].

Comment: 'tag__not_in' => array('с'),

Comment: 'tag__slug_in' => array('с'), тоже не сработал

Comment: Код в вопрос добавьте. Неизвестно, как вы там это всё делали.

Comment: И потом, вы так и не прочитали документацию. И даже не прочитали то, что я вам написал. Где вы откопали строку `tag__slug_in`?